# No me reproduce el video en firefox

Tags: html, html5, video, firefox

tengo un problema con los vídeos y no sé por qué no me funciona correctamente en firefox.

En el HTML he creado el tag de HTML5 de vídeo y he insertado varios formatos de vídeo para que se vea correctamente en los navegadores

```
<video id="video" poster="img_video.png" width="88%" loop controls tabindex="5">
  <source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="./video.wmv" type="video/wmv">
  <source src="./video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="./video.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Al probarlo en los navegadores (Chrome, edge, explorer, Opera y firefox), se carga bien en todos los navegadores y cuando le doy al play, en el único que me falla es en firefox que se me queda en blanco como intentando arrancar pero no lo reproduce.

Alguien me podría ayudar para que me funcione correctamente en éste navegador también?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿ Puedes comprobar que en las opciones de firefox (escribiendo about:config en la barra de direcciones) la línea media.windows-media-foundation.enabled  este en **TRUE** ?

También prueba cambiando el orden de los videos, poniendo en primer lugar el mp4 y en segundo lugar el webm

Otra opción que puedes probar, añade al webm la etiqueta codecs="vp8.0, vp9.0"

Comment: La línea _media.windows-media-foundation.enabled_ no la encuentro he revisado la lista y no la he visto. he modificado el orden de los vídeos y no me funciona y he modificado el código `<source src="./video.webm" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8.0, vp9.0">`y me sigue sin funcionar en firefox

Comment: El html lo tienes en local o en servidor ? En caso de ser en servidor, localiza el archivo mime.types y agrega 
AddType video/ogg .ogm
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/ogg .ogg

Comment: Lo he probado en local y en el servidor y en ninguno de los 2 me funciona, se me queda pensando pero no se reproduce, pero si abro los vídeos con un reproductor de vídeo cualquiera se me reproducen todos correctamente

Comment: al parecer es problema de mi portátil, que en el de un compañero se ve y se reproduce correctamente

Comment: Por lo que he estado viendo, debes modificar el archivo mime.types, y .htacces y añadir AddType video/ogg  .ogv
AddType video/mp4  .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm para que firefox pueda reproducirlo, de lo contrario no cargará el video. EDITO: Entonces puede que sea problema de tu version de firefox o de los codecs instalados si en otro pc los repoduce

Comment: veré a ver que le pasa a mi portátil, pero ya me quedo más tranquilo sabiendo que sí se ve correctamente en otros ordenadores